How to optimize a function subject to have unique vector equality
We start with a vector $x \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1}$ where every fourth entry starting from the first (i.e., entries 1, 5, 9, 13, ..., and so on up to the nearest index less than or equal to N) is set to zero. The non-zero entries in $x$ are randomly generated such that the norm of each entry is 1. This vector $x$ is multiplied by a unitary matrix $G$ and a discrete Fourier transform matrix $F$ to produce another vector $y = F G x$. Subsequently, $y$ is convolved with a channel vector $h$ to obtain $s = y * h = HFGx$, where $H$ is the circular convolution matrix constructed from $h$. Given that the last part of $y$, denoted as $y_p$, is known, how can we find a vector $g$ that, when multiplied by $s$, recovers the zero values in $x$, while ensuring that $s_p = y_p$ remains true?
This question involves projecting part of the matrix $FG_0$ (where $G_0$ consists of the rows of $G$ corresponding to the zero entries in $x$) onto the received vector $s$, under the condition that $s_p = y_p$. If we ignore the condition $s_p = y_p$ and only consider that each $x_i$ has a norm of 1, we might seek an eigenvector corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue of the matrix pair. However, the focus here is on determining $g$ such that the condition $s_p = y_p$ is satisfied.
